# Starting and keeping a session in IVR

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, ivr

How do I keep a session in IVR? I am halfway done with an IVR application I am currently working on. I can collect customer ID & PIN to read out customer balance. After a customer confirms account balance, I want them to be able to continue with other options of PIN change, transfer credits to another customer without having to collect the Customer ID & PIN again till the call finally end. I am using Twilio webhook and my code is in php. Any help and idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio respects cookies , so you should have no problem with persistence .
You can view how twilio cookies with here https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136287-How-do-Twilio-cookies-work-
 a more complex way would be to store the callsid and any data you want to persist in a database

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Onboarding Support here.

You could send the pin and customer id to the action on that gather as a custom param, the action url would then be able to query the paramer $_REQUEST[customID']:

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Twiml;

$response = new Twiml();
$gather = $response->gather(['input' => 'speech dtmf', 'timeout' => 3,
    'numDigits' => 1], 'action' => '/action&customID='+ $custCode + '+&pin=' + $pin');
$gather->say('Please press enter your customer id and pin or say sales for sales.');

echo $response;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer my question. Perhaps, I should put it simpler. Is it possible to start a session and keep the session variables active till the end of the call? I've tried setting sessions and cookies but none of them seem to work.